# Python mysql connector load statement searching in wrong directory Windows

Tags: python, mysql, windows, xampp, connector

Using code:

```
import mysql.connector
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='usr', password='pswd',
                              host='127.0.0.1',
                              database='db')

cursor = cnx.cursor()

cursor.execute(
    "LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\csvFiles\\Lamborghini-data.csv' "
    "INTO TABLE lamborghini "
    "FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' "
    "ENCLOSED BY '\"' "
    "LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n' "
    "IGNORE 1 ROWS "
    "(model_year, make, model, model_info, price, status, auction_location, auction_year);"
)
```

I successfully connect to the db, but the load statement for some reason looks for the files in the 'C:\xampp\mysql\data...', and not the path specified.

Here's the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "createAndLoadDB.py", line 42, in <module>
    "LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:\\Users\\david\\Documents\\MecumProject2\\MecumScraper\\csvFiles\\Lamborghini-data.csv' "
  File "C:\Users\david\Anaconda3\envs\MecumDBEnv\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 566, in execute
    self._handle_result(self._connection.cmd_query(stmt))
  File "C:\Users\david\Anaconda3\envs\MecumDBEnv\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 549, in cmd_query
    result = self._handle_result(self._send_cmd(ServerCmd.QUERY, query))
  File "C:\Users\david\Anaconda3\envs\MecumDBEnv\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 438, in _handle_result
    raise errors.get_exception(packet)
mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 29 (HY000): File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\UsersdavidDocumentsMecumProject2MecumScrapercsvFilesLamborghini-data.csv' not found (Errcode: 2 "No such file or directory")
```

It seems to be removing the '\\' from the file I specify, and searching for it in 'C\xampp\mysql\data...'.

I can execute the statement successfully if the statement is in a .sql file, but when use it in my python script mysql.connector throws the above error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why your file path would start with `C:\xampp\mysql\data\`?

This problem associate with your `secure_file_priv`. For example, my `my.ini` is

```
[mysqld]
secure_file_priv = "D:\MySQL\datas"
```

So i can only load the csv which under `D:\MySQL\datas`. But you can set `secure_file_priv = ""` to disable this option.

> How to stop removing the '\' from the file I specify?

Add `r` in front of your string, and you need to keep using `\\`. Why cause this, it might due to multiple passing, the string passes from Python to mysql.

```
r"""LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:\\abc\\def.csv'
INTO TABLE test 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '\"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS
(col);"""
```